# Change database column type in hook_update_N

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a column in my database, its type is `int`. Now I need to store decimal numbers. How can I change its type to `decimal` with [`hook_update_N`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In basic terms you just need to call [`db_change_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_change_field/7) in your update function, with the spec for the new field:

```
function MYMOUDLE_update_7001(&$sandbox) {
  // Create the definition for the field
  $new_field = array(
    'type' => 'decimal',
    'precision' => 16,
    'scale' => 2,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    // etc...
  );

  db_change_field('table_name', 'field_name', 'field_name', $new_field);
}
```

If your field is a primary key/part of an index, you'll need to manually drop those indicies and recreate them (see the documentation page for a more detailed explanation).

Comment: Also make sure that your previous type can be converted to the new one. This is usually less a problem with MySQL but PostgreSQL is way more strict there.

Comment: Shouldn't the type be `numeric` instead of `decimal`?

Comment: I want to change type from varchar to int. I have changed code as 'type' => 'int', 'size' => '255', 'not null' => TRUE, but its not changing the type in db.